# State changes in entities or components

Tags: component-based, state

I'm having some trouble figuring how to deal with state management in my entities.

I don't have trouble with Game state management, like pause and menus, since these are not handled as an entity component system; just with state in entities/components.

Drawing from Orcs Must Die as an example, I have my MainCharacter and Trap entities which only have their components like PositionComponent, RenderComponent, PhysicsComponent.

On each update the Entity will call update on its components. I also have a generic EventManager with listeners for different event types.

Now I need to be able to place the traps: first select the trap and trap position then place the trap.

When placing a trap it should appear in front of the MainCharacter, rendered in a different way and following it around. When placed it should just respond to collisions and be rendered in the normal way.

How is this usually handled in component based systems?

(This example is specific but can help figure out the general way to deal with entities states.)

Comment: Can you add and remove entities' components based on input events? 
Perhaps you can change the trap's components when the states change. For example, while placing the trap it will have FollowComponent and RenderEffectComponnent. When it gets placed, you remove both Components and add CollisionComponent. (Edit: More clearly expressed by Martin Sojka)

Comment: Yes, i can, every input gets translated from a "HumanView" into game events, which, most of them, get first processed by my GameLogic class, which will check for example if the MainCharacter has enough money to place a trap, how it happens after that is what i'm trying to figure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One interesting application of a component system is that you can change an entity's components at *runtime* if you designed it to be able to handle such. The state of an entity thus becomes the sum of both which components are assigned to it and which values those hold.

For your example, you can first create the trap with a `BuildControllerComponent` (governing the reaction to player controls in build phase), a `PositionComponent` and a `RenderComponent`. The last one has one data field which governs the pixel shader(s) used, and one of them gives the trap-to-be-build a "ghostly" look. You'll notice there are *no* physics components assigned yet.

Upon placing the trap, the components get exchanged. The `BuildControllerComponent` isn't needed anymore, so it gets removed. The `RenderComponent`'s shaders get replaced with your normal standard view of the trap. Finally, `PhysicsComponent` as well as whatever else is needed for the trap to work are added to the entity.

In an inheritance-based approach, this is equivalent to having a constructor for an `ActiveTrapEntity` class which takes a `BuildTimeTrapEntity` class as its arguments, the second one being used to render the trap during building it, the first one being used for the trap after it's in place.

Comment: This is clever.

Comment: This is good strategy for *applying* the state of an entity. It doesn't address the issue of how to track the state of each entity. How do you know which state the entity is currently in?

Comment: @MartinSojka This comes near what i was thinking about after asking the question. I was considering adding a BuildTrapProcess (Something that is updated at GameLogic) that will manage the runtime aspect of changing components to achieve the state changes needed to build a trap. When the button for building a trap gets pressed the game logic would create the Process and start it. any thoughts on this approach?

Comment: @Byte56: In general, you can query the associated components and its values. In practice, you often only need to know the relevant subset of the whole state, for example "Does this entity have `BuildControllerComponent`?" or "What is the position of this entity as recorded in its `PositionComponent`, if it has any?" - those you do by checking the component list for the ones you're interested in and optionally querying (some of) their values.

Comment: @GriffinHeart: I'd just implement whatever is needed to "build" the trap in the system associated with managing `BuildControllerComponent`s. It already needs to process player character's (or camera's) viewpoint changes and key and mouse press events.

Answer (score 5):

I don't like the idea of entities calling updates on their components (systems should be doing the work), and that's going to lead to issues with keeping components unaware of each other.

You can add an additional component called "State". It will be accessed by your render and collision systems. The state component is just a flag that has multiple states available to it. For the situation you describe the states would be `Play` and `Build`. When the render system sees that the state is `Build` it will draw the object translucent. When the collision system sees the `Build` state, it will not process collisions with the player.

But really, if you don't have systems and you're relying on components to do all the work you're going to run into a lot of issues. Components shouldn't know about each other and they shouldn't be doing processing.

Comment: What you're saying is conflicting, first they should be unaware (which i agree) then you follow by having a component that is accessed by others. Can you clarify? I'm keeping components decoupled by the event system.

Comment: I'm saying both. I'm saying they should be unaware and trying to tailor my response to how I think you're handling components. When you say "Entity will call update on its components" it makes me believe that you don't have systems processing entities. I've removed the confusing language and just made it say systems. I was saying components because I was understanding that that is how you were updating.

Comment: I like the idea of a `StateComponent` that can be consumed by multiple systems.

Comment: It's polite to provide reasoning for downvotes. Thanks.

Comment: -1: This suggestion is to add a magic special component to track state (which will grow in complexity over time) that may or may not be used by different components and hence removes half the benefit of using component based design in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for responding Sean. It's not really a magic component. It's a component like all the others. I think you mean it may not be used by different *systems*, but I would say that it would. Just in the answer I provided there are two systems that would utilize this component.

Comment: @Byte56 If you need to handle state for other kind of entities, would you create other State components?

Comment: On a different note, your objection to the asker's approach is based on the assumption that all component based design must update components from separate systems (like an entity system design).  That is one way to do it, but certainly not the only one, and there's no reason to dissuade such an approach for a game that has no need for cache-optimizing component update loops.

Comment: OK, that's just my opinion. I think components knowing about each other is a bad way to go about it. The complexity increases far faster than when using systems to manage entities. However Asakeron raises a valid point and this method could get out of hand if you're managing the states for lots of different types of entities.

Comment: @Byte56: I think your solution is sound. But instead of the editor recognizing the 'Build' component to mean that collisions should be disabled, wouldn't it be easier if the 'Build' component's job includes disabling collisions on the entity if it has a 'Physics' component, like setting the attribute 'CanCollide' to false?

Comment: @ViteFalcon Yes, that could work. It seems the OP is using events to make components talk to each other, so the in the event of adding the Build component the other components the event manager could change the other components as required.

Comment: @Byte56 i have my entities calling update on my components, but not every component will need update. For example my Physics components does, but its a simple one that only deals with applying velocity and changing the PositionComponent. My RenderComponent doesn't need update it just signals the GameView that it was created and implements a Draw method that the GameView will call.

Comment: @GriffinHeart How does the render component get access to the position component? Or the physics component get access to the position component?

Comment: @Byte56 The Component has a pointer to its entity, and the entity allows to fetch its components. The PositionComponent is kind of a bad example, since its used by many components. One could argue it belongs in the PhysicsComponent but static objects don't need Physics. At the moment, with the Components i have there's no coupling besides the PositionComponent.

Comment: @Byte56: Certainly it's good to be careful about dependencies. :) It's difficult to remove them entirely, though, especially for logic components (components whose sole purpose is to add game behavior).  There's also _many_ valid use cases for component based design where tight coupling makes sense; for example, physics vs collision vs triggers vs pathing vs animation etc.  even with systems, physics needs to know which objects are colliding and their contact manifolds (not all objects which collide have physics, e.g. trigger zones, AI sensor cones, etc.).